# how to reboot centos server by PHP

Tags: php

I used below codes for restart centos Server.

```
exec("reboot -h now");
```

and

```
shell_exec("reboot -h now");
```

but this codes not working.

please help me.

Comment: ask you host to enable these function for your account or if you have your vps you can enable it and it will work

Comment: are u using vps or host?

Comment: @sismaster i have vps,  exec & shell_exec enable but "reboot -h now" not working

Comment: @mohan21 i using vps

Comment: Most servers will disable administrative operation to be carried out thru web server service such as apache / php. You need to ask your server admin to enable it for you (if they agree)